# get request is not working on android device however it's working on my pc

Tags: java, android, okhttp

I've wrote this simple get request

```
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient();
StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder(serverURL);

String result = "init";
if(params!=null && params.size()!=0){
    url = url.append("?"+prepareParam(params));
}
Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url.toString()).build();
Response response = null;
try {
response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute();
result = response.body().string();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}finally {
    response.close();
}
```

when i tested it on my pc it worked just fine however when i tested it on my mobile it gave me the following exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void okhttp3.Response.close()' on a null object reference
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  try{
      response.close();
  }
  catch(NullPointerException e){
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

inside finally block.

Comment: Or simple `if (response != null) { response.close(); }`

Comment: this is also valid.

Comment: thank you, but i was wondering why response was null on my phone and not on my pc

Comment: response = httpClient.newCall(request).execute(); this line response may be not instantiate due to any network error or permissions so you get null pointer error at finally blocking.

Comment: Before finally block two catch blocks are there. Debug that two line may be you will find out error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out rather then using this many try catch.

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
  String doGetRequest(String url) throws IOException {
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
        .url(url)
        .build();
    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
    return response.body().string();
  }
```

Then just call above method and pass your url whenever you need.

```
 String response =doGetRequest(yourUrl);
```

Comment: this gave me  `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` exception